# É correto lançar uma exceção dentro de um synchronized?

Tags: java, concorrência, totalcross

Em minha app existem algumas threads que acessam o banco de dados e controlo esta concorrência utilizando o Lock do totalcross.

Minha pergunta é: Eu posso permitir que exceções sejam lançadas dentro de um bloco synchronized ? ou tenho que fazer algo para que a exceção seja lançado fora de seu escopo ?

Hoje eu evito que isto aconteça.

Segue um exemplo de código utilizado:

```
    public int executeUpdate(int dbIdx, String sql) {

    int res = 0;

    // secure access for database resource
    synchronized (MainDB.lockDB) {

        try {

            Debug.debug(sql, Debug.DEBUG_LEVEL_DEBUG);

            // Create statement to execute query
            Statement st =  connPool[dbIdx].createStatement();

            // Execute query
            res = st.executeUpdate(sql);

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

Comment: Lançar ou tratar/capturar?

Comment: Tanto faz. O objetivo da pergunta era entender como o Totalcross se comporta quando o fluxo de execução é interrompido antes do final do escopo do synchronized, para entender se o lock é liberado ou não.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lançar exceções é um processo normal na desenvolvimento em Java. Não traz efeito colateral algum. A máquina virtual TotalCross tem tratamento de exceção muito semelhante ao da JVM.

No Stack Overflow internacional, fizeram uma resposta bem sucinta sobre o assunto: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2019350/4438007

Se a exceção é lançada e tratada dentro do bloco `synchronized`, não há segredo algum. Caso a exceção seja tratada além do bloco `synchronized`, o `lock` será devolvido (e, se alguma outra thread estiver parada esperando o `lock`, ela prosseguirá pois o `lock` está liberado) e a exceção será tratada onde ela for capturada.

Esse [artigo do Java World](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076868/learn-java/how-the-java-virtual-machine-handles-exceptions.html) fala em mais detalhes como a JVM trata as exceções. A [documentação da JVM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html) também é uma boa leitura para saber sobre o comportamento ao se lançar exceções (recomendo focar nas seções [2.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.6) e [2.10](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.10)).

Sobre sincronização, ocorre o mesmo que previsto na [documentação do Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.1): ao se chegar no final do bloco de execução, o `lock` é liberado.

Só para ressaltar, por hora, o TotalCross não permite usar métodos sincronizados, apenas blocos sincronizados.